# Make column for set of data

Tags: linux, bash

How can I make a new column for the set of data using Bash?
here the example of input

```
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
D E F
3 2 1
6 5 4
9 8 7
```

output that I need:

```
A B C 1 2 3
A B C 4 5 6
A B C 7 8 9
D E F 3 2 1 
D E F 6 5 4
D E F 9 8 7
```

Comment: Show code, which does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Input**

```
$ cat file
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
D E F
3 2 1
6 5 4
9 8 7
```

**Output**

```
$ awk '/^[0-9]+/{print head,$0;next}{head=$0}' file
A B C 1 2 3
A B C 4 5 6
A B C 7 8 9
D E F 3 2 1
D E F 6 5 4
D E F 9 8 7
```

**Explanation**

```
awk '/^[0-9]+/{                              # Look for line starts with digits
                 print head,$0;              # print variable head and current record/line/row
                 next                        # we are done, go to next line
     }
     {
       head=$0                               # If above statement /^[0-9]+/ was not true,
                                             # we come here, so save current record to variable head 
     }
    ' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat filename | while read line
 do 
  if [[ "$line" =~ [[:upper:]] ]]
  then 
     strng=$line
  elif [[ "$line" =~ [[:digit:]] ]]
  then 
     echo $strng" "$line
  fi
 done
```

Here we are reading a given file line by line and then checking to see if the line contains numbers or not. If it isn't i.e. is upper case, we set a variable to that line. If the line is a digit, we print the variable we created earlier along with the a space and the line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
awk '/^[A-Z]/{p=$0}; /^[0-9]/{print p, $0}' <<EOF
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
D E F
3 2 1
6 5 4
9 8 7
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

@try:

```
awk '/^[a-zA-Z]/{val=$0;next} {print val FS $0}'   Input_file
```

checking if a line is starting with alphabets then storing into a variable named val and dong next not to execute all next statements. So when this condition is not true then print val and current line.